# Adding a constraint for a field in Odoo

Tags: python, java, linux, sum, odoo

This is what I have to do:

"Add a field for registering children to the employee object. It is possible to enter several children and enter the first and last name and date of birth for each of them. Show the field on the form view, in the Private information tab, below the field for the number of children (children). Show the field only if the number of children is greater than 0."

I have done this:

@api.onchange('children', 'name_child', 'date_of_birth')
def onchange_usage(self):
if self.children > 0:
self.name_child = True
self.date_of_birth = True
else:
self.name_child = False
self.date_of_birth = False

```
children = fields.Integer(string='Children')
name_child = fields.Char(string='Name of the Child')
date_of_birth = fields.Date(string='Date of Birth')
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with this code? Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add invisible for the fields `name_child` and `date_of_birth`

`attrs="{'invisible':[('children', '=', 0)]}"`